# why an object resets after execution? edited

Tags: php, object, methods, execute

I'm not new to programming but I found myself questioning how a function restart after execution. I was taught that every time a method start, the property or variable set while the method running resets.

If a function below in PHP executes, the property of the object set disappears.
How does it work?

```
class test{
    public $prop1;

    function test1($prop){

        $prop1 = $prop;

        $this->prop1 = $prop1;
    }
}
$test = new test();
$test->test1("string");
echo $test->prop1;
```

As you can see the sample code above, it stores variable "$prop" at property "prop1".

But after execution, the property disappear and the variable $prop1 also disappear.

Can you explain the mechanism of this?

Or do i miss something very basic of programming?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "after execution"? Show us the code where you instantiate this class and invoke this method, and then check this value to find it has disappeared.

Comment: I just edited. Thanks

Comment: Your property is private so you can't access it like that outside of the class unless you either make it public or provide a public method to return the private value.

Comment: It should throw an error but you must have error reporting turned off. Copy this line into your file and run it again: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: oh It should be public not private, and thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses a [garbage collector](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php). When a variable becomes unreachable, it is destroyed.

Regarding your code - the value of the `$prop` argument will not be destroyed after the method `test1()` finishes because you store it in the `$prop1` property. `$test->prop1` is still reachable after `test1()` exits (even if not directly).

```
class test
{
    private $prop1;

    function test1($prop)
    {
        $prop1 = $prop;

        $this->prop1 = $prop1;
    }
}

$test = new test();

$test->test1('hello');

var_dump($test);
```

Output:

```
object(test)#1 (1) {
  ["prop1":"test":private]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property needs to be public, or returned by a public getter, in order to access it outside of the class. Normally the code would have failed with the message:

`Fatal error: Cannot access private property test::$prop1 in xxx.php on line x`

But with error reporting turned off (or being directed to a log file that isn't being checked ;)) `echo $test->prop1;` doesn't execute, and there is no output from the program, giving the impression that the variable is empty.

`error_reporting(E_ALL);` will make the program fail with the appropriate message.